# ASP.NET MVC 5 Cannot Add Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

all,

Just wanted to add to the body of knowledge.  I was confounded, trying many solutions, when I couldn't add a controller to just one MVC project.  I was getting the error:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator:
'The parameter is incorrect [...] '
```

Answer below...

Comment: Thank you for this.  The question would be even better if you expanded it to match the site format by separating the question and answer.  Self answers are acceptable (and encouraged!), and are much clearer than a question with the answer in the body.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it that way

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be very obvious, but since it wasted my time, here you go:

I had saved my web.config file using Save as... to another location as a backup before making changes. The project was tracking the saved copy instead of the one in the project. It looked the same in the Solution Explorer, of course. Remove, add existing, et voila.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by Excluding the Web.Config from the project and then Including it in the project

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple close your **web.config** file(or any system file) and try again. It will work.